# How toc create relations between category and subcategories

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8

I have `categories` and `subcategories` tables

**Table** `catgeories`:

```
id
title
description
```

**Table** `subcategories`:

```
id
category_id
parent_category_id
```

Data for `categories` table:

[image]

Data for `subcategories` table

[image]

In my case any category has unlimited child categories. How to make relations **Many To Many** for models to get all categories and there subcategories?

Comment: Why don't you consider putting the subcategories in the same table, and assigning it parent_category_id of the parent.

Then in Category Model:
You would have:

public function subCategories(){
  return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_category_id');
}

In the end: Category::with('subCategories')->all();

isn't this easy ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to keep the categories in same table like below

| id | parent_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | parent cat |
| 2 | 1 | child cat |

In the above table parent_id which has 0 value are the actual parent categories, and which has number are child categories, eg: child cate is child of parent cat, in this way you can implement infinite child categories. But Don't worry we can achieve the relations as you have done, please follow as below

Am Assuming categories and subcategories as model. In categories model write a relation as below

```
public function childCategories(){
      return $this->hasMany('\App\subcategories','parent_category_id','id')
                 ->join('categories','categories.id','=','subcategories.categories')
                 ->select("categories.title",'subcategories.*');
}
```

After the when you calling the categories call it via **with** as below, you will get categories with related sub categories

```
$categories = categories::with('childCategories')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the category or, the sub-category, you can use this

```
$allSubCategory = DB::table('sub_categories')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                    ->join('categories', 'sub_categories.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                    ->select('sub_categories.*', 'categories.category_name')
                    ->get();
    
    $allCategory = DB::table('categorys')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                    ->join('sub_categories', 'categorys.category_id', '=', 'sub_categories.id')
                    ->select('categorys.*', 'sub_categories.sub_category_name')
                    ->get();
```